# Regular expression to fix my long string that only partially repeats format

Tags: php, regex

I have this string that I want to clean up using PHP and regex:

```
Name/__text,Password/__text,Profile/__text,Locale/__text,UserType/__text,Passwor
dUpdateDate/__text,Columns/0/Name/__text,Columns/0/Label/__text,Columns/0/Order/
__text,Columns/1/Name/__text,Columns/1/Label/__text,Columns/1/Order/__text,Colum
ns/2/Name/__text,Columns/2/Label/__text,Columns/2/Order/__text,Columns/3/Name/__
text,Columns/3/Label/__text,Columns/3/Order/__text,Columns/4/Name/__text,Columns
/4/Label/__text,Columns/4/Order/__text,Columns/5/Name/__text,Columns/5/Label/__t
ext,Columns/5/Order/__text,Columns/6/Name/__text,Columns/6/Label/__text,Columns/
6/Order/__text,Columns/7/Name/__text,Columns/7/Label/__text,Columns/7/Order/__te
xt,Columns/8/Name/__text,Columns/8/Label/__text,Columns/8/Order/__text,Columns/9
/Name/__text,Columns/9/Label/__text,Columns/9/Order/__text,Columns/10/Name/__tex
t,Columns/10/Label/__text,Columns/10/Order/__text,Columns/11/Name/__text,Columns
/11/Label/__text,Columns/11/Order/__text,Columns/12/Name/__text,Columns/12/Label
/__text,Columns/12/Order/__text,Columns/13/Name/__text,Columns/13/Label/__text,C
olumns/13/Order/__text,MailAddress/__text,Description/__text,Columns/14/Name/__t
ext,Columns/14/Label/__text,Columns/14/Order/__text,Columns/15/Name/__text,Colum
ns/15/Label/__text,Columns/15/Order/__text
```

I want it to be `Password,Profile,Locale,UserType,PasswordUpdateDate,Name,Label,Order...`

I'm removing the `/text` or `/__text` after the word, but there are only sometimes things like `Columns/0/` before the word to remove.

I tried this (below) regular expression in the regex tester, but it misses the first few items that don't have the `Columns/2/` type of thing before it.  I can't use a regex that will grab what's before `/__text`, because the `/` before the word is optional, like for the first `Name`.  Any ideas how to do this? It's tough to search for this pattern or info on how to create it. Any help would be great!

```
[A-Za-z\/0-9]+\/([A-Za-z]+)\/[__text]
```

Comment: _Password,Profile,Locale,UserType,PasswordUpdateDate,Name,Label,Order..._ as it states.

Comment: try with `preg_match_all('/[^,]+(?=__text)/', ... ...);`

Comment: @kip it matches the first few except it adds the trailing /, but then when it gets to the /Columns/0/word ones, it starts grabbing the whole thing.

Comment: @Michele I got it, sorry, maybe `[^/,]+(?=/_)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easier to just match what you want and then join them on commas.  Match a word `(\w+)` followed by `\__text`:

```
preg_match_all('#(\w+)/__text#', $string, $matches);
$result = implode(',', $matches[1]);
```

You could also use `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` and add anything else instead of `(\w+)` in case it could be `First_Name`, `First-Name`, `Firstname0` etc...

Comment: I tested it in the regex editor and it was perfect without the #'s.  Thanks!

Comment: Well somebody didn't like it, maybe the other answerer? ;-)

Comment: LOL, or revo!  :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver, wasn't me :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Why do you have those #'s?  Do I need them when I put the regex in php? When I try what you have in php without the #'s like I had in the regex tester, $matches is null.

Comment: Yes, they are delimiters and required, but you could use something else like `!` or `@` or many other things.  I normally use `/` but since there is a `/` in the pattern it would need to be escaped.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Do you mean this?  preg_match_all('/(/\w+)/__text/', $line, $matches); When I try that, I still get null back for $matches.

Comment: Just use the pound signs or you have to escape the / with a \

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
(\w+)\/__text(?:(,)(?:Columns\/\d+\/)*)*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ud6KUT/2)

Explanation:

```
/(\w+)\/__text(?:(,)(?:Columns\/\d+\/)*)*/g
1st Capturing Group (\w+)
    \w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
    + Quantifier — Matches between one and  unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
__text matches the characters __text literally (case sensitive)
Non-capturing group (?:(,)(?:Columns\/\d+\/)*)*
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    2nd Capturing Group (,)
    , matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
    Non-capturing group (?:Columns\/\d+\/)*
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    Columns matches the characters Columns literally (case sensitive)
    \/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
    \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
    \/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: @Matt-g - How would you do that with php?  Does it need any escaped characters? Would it be this? It's not returning anything in $matches.....          $success = preg_match('/(\w+)\/__text(?:(,)(?:Columns\/\d+\/)*)*/g', $line, $matches);

Comment: @Michele, `preg_match_all('/(\w+)\/__text(?:(,)(?:Columns\/\d+\/)*)*/', $string, $matches);
$result = implode(',', $matches[1]);` [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da586cf74b3ccb4efaf52fd63e8025e6708b88a2)